# Is Java necessary to create an AMI?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I've been reading Amazon EC2 doc, and you can create the AMI with the AMI tools, but, for registering (and then be able to use it for insert in new instances), you need EC2 API  tools, and they need Java.

Is it necessary then to install all Java package in a host, to register a just created AMI?

I find it unnecessary because Java installation takes too much space and performance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Amazon GUI to create the AMI instead?

Comment: The AWS console is at http://console.aws.amazon.com. You can do all of this there. Alternatively, if you're programming in a specific programming language, Amazon offers official SDKs for Java, C#, PHP, iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

Not all the tools require java, you can use the ruby ones for example

http://solutious.com/blog/2009/04/22/rudy-ec2-api-tools-replacement/ or Tim kay perl tools

http://timkay.com/aws/

However these are not offical tools, but 3rd party created tools.